# How to blur all text in an image automatically

Tags: automation, blur

Is there a way to blur just the text in any image, automatically?

I have a lots of PNG images with text(s) in them. And I have to blur all of it from all of them.

Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Could you please give a bit more detail of what you're trying to achieve, maybe by way of an example? What software are you using?

Comment: @Bakabaka I'm trying to blur all the text in an image. I'll take a look at any software that does this.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply apply a blur to the **entire image** as a whole?

Comment: @Scott sorry, yes: I do not want to blur other elements.

Comment: This post is really questionable to me. It sounds like you have a bunch of images/designs/photos with watermarks/copywriting in the corner, and you want us to help you find the best way to remove them in an automated process. I know of a way to do this, but will refrain from posting the answer because this is SHADY....

Answer (score 2):

In order to automatically blur text in an image, you first need some way of detecting that there is text in it. Image recognition is quite complex and resource intensive, so you would need something like OCR, and then something else to blur the detected areas. I personally don't know of any tools to do this.

What you can do is blur the images manually, using Photoshop, Gimp or similar. The procedure will be similar for both programs: Select an area with the selection tool, and apply a Gaussian blur to the selection. In Photoshop, you can automate this process by saving the blur as an [action](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSFC3351AF-238A-424f-99BC-ABF419177233.html), so you would need to manually make the selection of the areas you want to blur, and then apply the action.

Comment: Going one step further, if the text is always in the same spot you can create an action and then use a batch process to apply it to as many images as you want with only needing to run it once (rather than re-selecting on every image).